# Flutter redraw appbar

Tags: flutter

I’m creating an appbar that is supposed to change color if the device is connected to the internet or not. The bar is supposed to be red when not connected and blue when connected. Everything works fine, but the changes does not appear before I navigate to a new page. I want this changes to happen right away.

Here is my code:

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {

  static AppBarChoices choices = new AppBarChoices();

  MyAppBar({Key key, Widget title})
    : super(key: key, title: title, backgroundColor: choices.getColor() , actions: <Widget> [choices.getText(), choices.getIcon()]);

}

class AppBarChoices {
  App app = new App();

  Color _color = new Color(0xff023570);
  Icon _icon = new Icon(Icons.wifi);
  Text _text = new Text('');

  updateAppBar(bool isOnline){
    if (isOnline){
      _color = new Color(0xff023570);
      _icon = new Icon(Icons.wifi);
      _text = new Text('');
    } else {
      _color = new Color(0xffD0021B);
      _icon = new Icon(Icons.signal_wifi_off);
      _text = new Text('no internet accsess');
    }
  }

  getColor(){
    return _color;
  }

  getIcon(){
    return _icon;
  }

  getText(){
    return _text;
  }
}
```

Any of you know how i could get this to update right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never *extend* a widget. Instead, you should use composition.

Then, following this principle you should transform your widget into a `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` on connection change.

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
  Color _color = new Color(0xff023570);
  Icon _icon = new Icon(Icons.wifi);
  Text _text = new Text('');

  @override
  void initState() {
    watchConnectionStateChange();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: _color,
      actions: <Widget>[_text, _icon],
    );
  }

  void watchConnectionStateChange() {
    // TODO: watch connectionStateChange
    // connection.onChange((value) {
    //   setState(() {
    //       color = value == hasInternet ? Color(0xff023570) : Color(0xffD0021B);
    //   })
    // })
  }
}
```